# Show that the set $P_F$ of all polynomial functions on $F$ forms a subring of $F^F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $F$ be a field. An element $\phi$ of $F^F$ is a polynomial function on $F$, if there exists $f\in F[x]$ such that $\phi (a)=f(a)$ for all $a \in F$.

> Show that the set $P_F$ of all polynomial functions on $F$ forms a subring of $F^F$.

I know we are suppose to use homomorphisms but I don’t understand how or why. I’m just really struggling with this proof as a whole, so the more detail the better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hints*: Can you define a map from $F[x]\to F^F$? (That is, for any element of $F[x]$, what function from $F$ to itself does it correspond to?)

Next, once you've done that, you should show that the map is a homomorphism of rings. What are the operations in each of these rings?

Finally, what do you know about the image of a ring under a ring homomorphism?

Comment: So let $\gamma : F[x] \to F^F$ such that $\gamma (f(a)) = \phi (a) = f(a)$. Does that work?

Comment: That's the right idea, but $f(a)$ is not an element of $F[x]$; rather it is an element of $F$; the result of applying $f$ to $a$. See the difference? What you need to do is to say: if $f\in F[x]$, what is $\gamma(f)$?

Comment: So how about $\gamma f(a) = \phi_a (f) = f(a)$ for all a$\in F$?

Comment: Yes. In other words, $\gamma f$ is that element of $F^F$ that sends each element of $F$ to the same place as $f$ does.

Comment: So next I need to show that for let’s say $\psi \in P_F$ that $\psi (a+b) = \psi (a) + \psi (b)$ and the same for multiplication?

Comment: Or is it for $f(x), g(x) \in F[x]$ that $\gamma (f(x)+g(x)) = \phi_x (f)+\phi_x (g) = f(x)+g(x)$?

Comment: The latter: $\gamma$ takes functions (in $F[x]$) to functions (in $F^F$). Also, since these are both rings, you need to also show that $\gamma(fg) = \gamma(f)\gamma(g)$.

Comment: (This is probably clear to you, but anyway...) To show that $\gamma(f+g) = \gamma(f) + \gamma(g)$, you need to show that they agree on all elements of $F$; that is, that $(\gamma(f+g))(a) = (\gamma(f))(a) + (\gamma(g))(a)$ for all $a\in F$.

Comment: Trust me, nothing in this problem is clear to me. Haha. Anyway though, how about this, let f,g $\in F[x]$ such that $\gamma (f(a)) = \phi_a(f) =f(a)$ and $\gamma (g(a)) = \phi_a(g) =g(a)$ for all $a\in F$. Then we have,  $\gamma (f(a)+g(a)) = \phi_a(f) + \phi_a(g) =f(a) + g(a)$.

Comment: Not quite. $(\gamma(f+g))(a) = (f+g)(a) = f(a) + g(a)$. Remember that $\gamma$ almost does nothing: it simply "thinks" of a polynomial in $F[x]$ as being instead a member of a larger class: all functions from $F$ to $F$.

Comment: Ok. And then the same with $\gamma (fg)(a) = (f)(g)(a) = f(a)g(a)$? Also, why are we proving homomorphism? How does that help prove it is a subring?

Comment: If $\varphi:R\to S$ is a ring homomorphism, do you know any theorems that tell you something about the image of $R$ under $\varphi$?

Comment: The image of R under $\psi$ is {$\psi (r)| r\in R$}?

Comment: Yes, that's how it's defined. Can you show that the image of $\phi$ is a subring of $S$?