# Show that the set $P_F$ of all polynomial functions on $F$ forms a subring of $F^F$. using the subring test

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I am aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759276/show-that-the-set-p-f-of-all-polynomial-functions-on-f-forms-a-subring-of-ff) question but I think the proof in that question uses homomorphisms (I think) while I want to use the [Subring Test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subring_Test) to prove the following statement.

Let $F$ be a field. An element $\phi$ of $F^F$ is a polynomial function on $F$, if there exists $f(x) \in F[x]$ such that $\phi (a)=f(a)$ for all $a \in F$. For $\phi, \psi \in F^F,$ define the sum $\phi + \psi$ by $(\phi + \psi)(r) = \phi(r) + \psi(r)$ and the product $\phi \cdot \psi$ by $(\phi \cdot\psi)(r) = \phi(r) \cdot \psi(r)$ for all $r \in F$.

> Show that the set $P_F$ of all polynomial functions on $F$ forms a subring of $F^F$. Here's my attempt thus far:

**Proof.** Firstly, we show that $P_F$ is closed under subtraction. Let $\gamma, \beta \in P_F$. Then, there exist $f(x), g(x) \in F[x]$ such that $\gamma (a)=f(a)$ and $\beta (a)=g(a)$ for all $a \in F$. Then, $(\gamma - \beta)(a) = \gamma(a) - \beta(a) = f(a) - g(a) = (f-g)(a)$. Here, we have shown that $(f- g) \in F[x]$ is s.t. $(\gamma - \beta) (a)=(f-g)(a)$. So, by definition, $P_F$ is closed under subtraction.

Secondly, we show that $P_F$ is closed under multiplication. Let $\gamma, \beta \in P_F$. Then, there exist $f(x), g(x) \in F[x]$ such that $\gamma (a)=f(a)$ and $\beta (a)=g(a)$ for all $a \in F$. Then, $(\gamma \cdot \beta)(a) = \gamma(a) \cdot\beta(a) = f(a) \cdot g(a) = (f \cdot g)(a)$ and we are done.

Lastly, we show that $P_F$ is nonempty. *This is where I run into trouble. I have no clue as to how this should be proved. I attempted a proof by contradiction to no avail.* **Can someone please show how this can proved? Also, is my proof for closure under multiplication and subtraction accurate?**

I should note that I found an alternative rendition of the [Subring Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subring#Subring_test) according to which I need to prove that the multiplicative identity of $F^F$ is in $P_F$ (and won't need to prove that $P_F$ is nonempty) in addition to what I currently have. **Can someone show how this can be proved?**

Comment: To show a set is nonempty, exhibit a specific element of the set! Just pick your favorite polynomial that you know exists, and look at its image. As for the multiplicative identity... well, what function do you think will work, and what polynomial does it correspond to?

Comment: Your proof is fine, but it is very confusing to use $\circ$ to denote pointwise multiplication of *functions*, given that the symbol already has a meaning when applied to functions, namely “composition”. Anyone seeting this would think that $(\psi\circ\phi)(r) = \psi(\phi(r))$, and that $\psi(r)\circ\phi(r)$ does not make sense....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I've replaced $\circ$ with $\cdotp$. Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If I am trying to show that the set is non empty, would it be correct to pick $f(x) = x$? Since the set of real numbers is a field, $f(x) \in F[x]$ s.t. $\phi (x) = f(x) = x$ for all $x \in R$? Thanks!

Comment: That works. But note that the fact that the real numbers form a field has *absolutely nothing to do* with the fact that the identity is a polynomial function, though.... (Also, it’s usually easiest to show the zero element is in your subset, as that is the only element of the ring that you know for sure must lie in any subring... just like proving nonemptiness in linear algebra by showing the zero vector is there)